# How to do a license transfer for Visio 2003?

Tags: license, microsoft-visio

We've got some machines we'd like to install Visio 2007 on.  There are other machines that have Visio 2003 installed, where it's not really being used.  The plan is to transfer those licenses to the machines that need Visio, then upgrade to 2007.  Before buying the upgrades, I'd like to be sure I can actually do the transfer.  I've transferred an old XP license for my own PC upgrade before, but no experience with Office/Visio transfers.  Any tips or links to instructions?  I believe these were individual installs, not volume licensed, though I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's retail, you will have no problems. OEM then you have a problem, this will not allow to be moved over.

I have had to do this before, and the work around is to call up Microsoft, tell them the situation and they should be able to activate it for you

Answer (score 0):

Right...

A bit confused - but, if you have an upgrade licence, it simply upgrade your usage rights to the latest version. If your original version was a fully packaged product, you may transfer it to as many computers as you like, as often as you like - as long as you only have it installed at one place at a time.

If your original copy was not fully packaged and OEM, then you purchased upgrade - you only upgraded the instance on that machine and the licence lives with that machine.

The same goes for XP.

If I was you, install it on the new pc and you should not have any problems. If you do, simply ring the Microsoft free phone number, and they should be able to either activate your current copy or give you a new licence key.